# Flask log getting wrapped twice

Tags: python, flask, python-logging

When flask logs to file the log looks like this.
There is 2 dates and time:
one in the message(after >>>)
other before message

```
WARNING  2023-09-08 18:18:29 werkzeug >>>  * Debugger is active!
INFO     2023-09-08 18:18:29 werkzeug >>>  * Debugger PIN: 134-698-034
INFO     2023-09-08 18:18:32 werkzeug >>> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2023 18:18:32] "GET /signin_trainer HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2023-09-08 18:18:32 werkzeug >>> 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2023 18:18:32] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

My code for logging config

```py
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.log',
    format='{levelname:<8} {asctime} {name:<8} >>> {message}',
    style='{',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    encoding='utf-8', force=True)
```

I want to delete date and time from message body and leave my own(or some hack to achieve same result).
So the log would look like this

```
INFO     2023-09-08 18:18:32 werkzeug >>> 127.0.0.1 "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I tried googling, but nothing helped me